# SOAP: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"lastCallDate"). Expected elements are &lt;{}gracePeriod>,&lt;{}token>

Tags: xml, soap, postman

I am sending a SOAP request via POSTMAN (in XML format), but I am getting the above error. I intend to send the token as well as the lastCallDate parameters in the body of the SOAP request.

My request:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:plat="http://ws.digitalpaytech.com/plateInfo"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-8230F690FFEA8F015916382936150461">
                <wsse:Username>username@here</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password@here</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">rZrJA+y3RZ1yNvK9oun31A==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2021-12-01T22:28:21Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <plat:PlateInfoRequest>
            <token>token@here</token>
            <lastCallDate>2021-11-30T22:28:21Z</lastCallDate>
        </plat:PlateInfoRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But unfortunately, I am getting an Unmarshalling Error (as shown below). But surprisingly when I am removing/commenting the lastCallDate line, I get no errors and get the response successfully.

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"lastCallDate"). Expected elements are &lt;{}gracePeriod>,&lt;{}token> </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please suggest how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error meant that the request only accepted body & gracePeriod as parameters, and not lastCallDate.
[SOLVED]